# Launching PDFs programmatically despite Protected Mode

Tags: vb.net, process, acrobat

Short description: **is it at all possible to launch a PDF programmatically even if the option "Enable Protected Mode at startup" is Enabled in Acrobat Reader?**

---

**detailed:**
Having come across this problem years ago we had completely forgotten about it until it raised its ugly head again.

We have a program written in .NET code - the actual code doesn't matter as this is a generic problem.

In the code we would launch a PDF file from its path. And then suddenly this would no longer work. For ANY PDF, with spaces in the path or without, no matter. We tried many different ways. **Process.Start**, **Process.Start with Start Info and ShellExecute**, Literally finding the location of **AcroRd32.exe** and start it with the file name passed in as an Argument... Nothing worked.

Eventually we found the cause of the problem. In recent versions of Acrobat Reader, there is an Enhanced Security option - from the Acrobat Menu choose Edit - Preferences, choose Security (Enhanced) from the options on the left, and in the Dialog switch off - uncheck - "Enable Protected Mode at startup". After that our software would launch all PDFs successfully again.

So at the moment we are simply reading the Registry - see, for example, https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/protectedmode.html which explains the location to look for for Acrobat Reader 10.0 - the instructions for other versions are only trivially different.

If Protected Mode is switched on, we show a Message Box to the user informing them of the setting and instructing them how to switch it off.

All fine and dandy, and don't get me wrong. It works. But it means relying on the customer to make a change. They may not be able - or willing - to make that change to their system.

Please note that I'm not interested in suggestions that involve overriding the registry setting. That's too much of a "nasty hack" and our customers will not thank us for that.

Comment: That seems odd. Protected Mode shouldn't prevent PDFs from being opened, it should just open them with JavaScript disabled. I suspect there is soimething else going on. Have you tried launching Reader and then opening the file via DDE?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that.... I didn't even know that was possible :D - I'll read up on that and I'll see whether that's an option. In any case.... All I know is that disabling the option stopped the problem from occurring. I forgot to mention though: when the option is enabled I would see two AcroRd32 processes appear in my Task Manager. They just never show any UI.

Comment: What version of Reader are you using? What happens if Acrobat is the client?

Comment: Acrobat Reader DC - I even uninstalled it and re-installed the most current version directly from Adobe. It didn't make a difference. Our customers, meanwhile, could be using any versions of Acrobat Reader. The less assumptions I would have to make about the Reader version, the better.

Comment: Given that there have been no actual working solutions to this I think we'll have to end up telling our customers to use something a little less despicable than Adobe software for opening PDFs. We might just send them this:

https://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-reader/

Scandalous